# Providing extra foreign keys

Tags: database-design

I am pretty new to databases and SQL.
Have following question, didn't figured out how to google this.

I am designing database structure for my application. Let's say I have following tables:

### user

- id (PK)
- department_id (FK)
- first_name
- last_name

### department

- id (PK)
- name

### task

- id (PK)
- user_id (FK)
- ? department_id (FK)

Should I add `department_id` into `task`, or maybe `user_id` will be sufficient?
In case if I want to figure out user's department while selecting data from `tasks`, how do I build the query for it?

UPD:

Let's assume we don't plan to change task's owner through time. I consider extra foreign keys only as shortucts to avoid extra joins while selecting data.

Example: let's assume we have one more table:

### session

- ID (PK)
- started_time
- task_id (FK)
- ? user_id (FK)

If I won't add `user_id`, I will need to perform two extra join, first to get `user_id` from `task_id` and then, to get `department_id` from `user_id`.

The question is - is this generally normal or bad practice?

Comment: If a user changes department, all his associated tasks also change their department? If so, you can omit the department FK on Task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In case if I want to figure out user's department while selecting data from `tasks`, how do I build the query for it?

You'd first join `user` and then `department`.

```
SELECT *
       FROM task
            INNER JOIN user
                       ON user.id = task_user.id
            INNER JOIN department
                       ON department.id = user.department_id;
```

Such "chains" of joins are no problem for a DBMS in general, it's built to do that (but you should consider proper indexing to support it (but that's also true for queries not using joins)). The "shortcuts" you have in mind on the other hand bring a certain level of denormalization and with that a handful of problems.

Whether to include `department_id` in `tasks` depends on what you're trying to model.

If a task can be assigned to a whole department without a specific user from that department, you'll need it. Add a check constraint enforcing that one of both is null, to be able to distinguish between task assigned to only a user and those only assigned to a department.

If only users can have tasks assigned, you won't need it. You can query the department as shown above. Further more in that case it's dangerous to include it or at least it makes things more complicated. You have to check then, that the integrity isn't violated. Say if a user assigned to a task is in department A but the department assigned to the task is B. That obviously doesn't match. Unless users can be in several departments an a task should be assigned to a user in the role as a member of a specific department. That's one of the problems of denormalization I mentioned above.

(You see, there are many ifs here, you need to think through. Maybe even more than I just came up with!)

If you don't need the `department_id` because of the logic, I'd recommend not to use it in `task`. It most likely brings more problems and doesn't even solve another as joining usually is no problem.

Comment: great answer, please see updated post

Comment: @JackHammer: I updated the answer to address your concerns about joining.